# FTDI + ESP8266 [Need to use AT Commands] without Arduino

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-ide, ftdi, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to write standalone ESP8266 code so that it can communicate to wifi and change its states. For this, what I want to do is to send some command "AT+CWMODE=1" or "AT+CWMODE=3" to ESP8266 via code and toggle them on push button tap.

So, like in Arduino there is a Serial.write which writes on a serial monitor via SoftwareSerial class.

But when I am sending `Serial.write("AT+CWMODE=1")` it prints on the monitor as a string rather than changing the wifi state.

Is there a way to send AT commands without using Arduino chip software serial pins?

Thanks.

Comment: Okay I am totally confused by this. You're having a USB FTDI adapter hooked up directly on your ESP8266. And on what device are you executing the `Serial.write()`? What firmware has the ESP8266 flashed?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Yes, I have usb ftdi adapter directly hooked up to my ESP8266. Esp8266-01 which has default firmware comes up if someone buy's this chip from online. I was trying to use these commands but none of the commands were working on it. Is it because of the firmware? Thanks.

Comment: How do you send serial commands? Have you tried minicom? What baud rate are you on? Do you see any serial output when you power on th esp8266 with your ftdi connected?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Hey I am trying to send serial commands through code. Serial.write("AT+CWMODE=1") or similar to change the wifi preferences from code, and so  that I can access this state from code (iOS/Android). I am having a baud rate of 9600, and haven't tried minicom before. And I haven't used any serial output when I power esp8266 through ftdi. Thanks.

Comment: After you uploaded your own Arduino core sketch firmware, you overwrote the AT firmware. You can't use the AT commands anymore. Just look at ESP8266 Arduino core examples how to use the WiFi parts.

Comment: Do I need to install NodeMcu firmware in esp8266-01 in order to access wifi classes which help me in accessing the AT indirectly, for creating it as an access point and allowing other computers to connect to me. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorted out the issue. All those who are new like me to ESP world, I did the serial.write "AT" commands using wifi classes of Esp8266.

You need to connect the board as ESP8266 Generic Module and send/receive data using ESP8266Wifi class, by reading the scanned networks, changing mode, using Serial.read on the connected devices on Access point of Esp8266.

Let me know if someone need help on this future, I will be happy to help.